# Why 'unassigned local viariable' error appear in one function but not in second very similar function

Tags: c#

so i trying to understand this thing
i have two similar functions

1. First function determine who win in paper,scissor, rock game using if/else blocks
2. Second function doing that same but using dictionares and key/values

The problem is first function work fine but in second function i got 
'*Use of unassigned local viarable*' error
I know to repair this i should change `string win1;`
 to `string win1 = "";`
but i dont understand why

First function code:

```
static string whowin(int x, int y)
{
    string win;
    if (x == 1)
    {
        if (y == 2)
        {
            win = "player2";
        }
        else if (y == 3)
        {
            win = "player1";
        }
        else
        {
            win = "draw";
        }
    }
    else if (x == 2)
    {
        if (y == 1)
        {
            win = "player1";
        }
        else if (y == 3)
        {
            win = "player2";
        }
        else
        {
            win = "draw";
        }
    }
    else // player 1 choose 3 - scissors
    {
        if (y == 2)
        {
            win = "player1";
        }
        else if (y == 1)
        {
            win = "player2";
        }
        else
        {
            win = "draw";
        }
    }
    return win;
}
```

and second function:

```
static string whowin2(int x, int y)
{
    // x- player 1 input, y- player 2 input
    // 1 - rock, 2- paper, 3 = scissors
    Dictionary<int, int> player1win = new Dictionary<int, int>() {
        { 1, 3 },
        { 2, 1 },
        { 3, 2 }
        };
     Dictionary<int, int> player2win = new Dictionary<int, int>() {
        { 1, 2 },
        { 2, 3 },
        { 3, 1 }
           };

    string win1;

    if (player1win.ContainsKey(x) && player1win[x].Equals(y))
    {
        win1 = "player1";
    }
    else if (player2win.ContainsKey(x) && player2win[x].Equals(y))
    {
        win1 = "player2";
    }
    else if (x == y)
    {
        win1 = "draw";
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cos cos sie popsuo");
    }
    return win1;
}
```

Comment: Hi, the reason is that in the first function win will always have a value assigned to it while in the second function it won't : else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cos cos sie popsuo");
            }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second method, there is an execution path where the `win1` variable is not set:

```
string win1;

if (...)
    [...]
else if (...)
    [...]
else if (...)
    [...]
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cos cos sie popsuo");
    // HERE
}
return win1;
```

When you enter the `else` branch your variable `win1` will not be set, so it is an "unassigned local viarable".

Answer (score 1):

The final else clause of the second function doesn't set win1 to any value.  Then your trying to return the value of win1, which the compiler sees has not been initialized.  So you are correct, declare win1 = String.Empty or "" and the compiler will be happy.

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler looks at your code it sees that it could fall into the final else condition, and it that case it would return win1 without that being set to anything hence use of unassigned local.  If you initialize on declaration you have set the variable before it is used.